# Is there a way for python file read to partition text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read text file formatted in this way

```
1      100
---stuff----
2      100
---stuff---
3      200
---stuff--
```

1 represents case ID and 100 means number of lines "stuff" occupies. Is there a way for me to read 1 100 and 2 100 separately in python?

Comment: Yes there most certainly is a way to do that. What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I tried using bash instead where gsplit -l 101 "filename" file. it didn't work out nicely as different case id occupies different number of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure of file :
(Note that the number lines are tab separated)

```
1   3
abc
def
ghi
2   2
jkl
mno
3   4
pqr
stu
vwx
yz
```

Now try :

```
f=open(filename)
all_lines=f.readlines() #read all lines

content=[] #empty list 

for i in range(len(all_lines)): #for each line
    if(len(all_lines[i].split('\t'))==2): #check if when you split by tab the line has two members only
        i=i+1
        c=[] #for the current segment
        while(i<len(all_lines) and len(all_lines[i].split('\t'))!=2): #until next segment is reached
            c.append(all_lines[i].strip()) #append to current segment
            i=i+1
        content.append(c) #append entire current segment to overall content

for c in content:
    print(c)
```

Output :

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
['jkl', 'mno']
['pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try generator approach :

```
with open('file','r') as f:
    def generator_approach():
        sub_=[]
        for line in f:

            if 'stuff' in line.strip():
                yield sub_
                sub_=[]
            else:
                sub_.append(line.strip())
        if sub_:
            yield sub_

    closure_=generator_approach()
    print(list(closure_))
```

output:

```
[['1      100'], ['2      100'], ['3      200']]
```